# Azure DevOps Pipeline: Processing Git Commit Files

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm writing an Azure DevOps (ADO) pipeline triggered by a pull request to master branch in which I'd like to extract a list of committed files and feed them as an input to a python script. So far, I have the following yaml file:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:

- checkout: self
fetchDepth: 1
clean: true

- bash: |
echo "list commit files"
export COMMIT_HASH=`git rev-parse --short HEAD`
export COMMIT_FILES=`git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $COMMIT_HASH`
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=VarFiles;isOutput=true]$COMMIT_FILES"
name: CommitFiles

- script: |
echo "commit files:"
echo $(CommitFiles.VarFiles)
name: PrintCommitFiles

- script: python src/cdl/sandbox/catalyst/adopipeline/validate-spark-config/validate_spark_config.py -f $(CommitFiles.VarFiles)
name: 'run pipeline'
```

However, the above YAML file only works if there is a single commit file. How do I make it work for multiple files? i.e. how do I retrieve the committed files for the last commit and feed them into a python script? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up merging the steps into powershell script and modifying the git diff command. Below is a working YAML script:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
   vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:

- checkout: self

- powershell: |
   Write-Output "Processing Commit Files:"
   $commit_hash = git rev-parse --short HEAD
   $commit_files = git diff --name-only $commit_hash^ $commit_hash
   python3 src/cdl/sandbox/catalyst/adopipeline/validate-spark-config/validate_spark_config.py --path $commit_files
```